# Как на github.com можно вывести доску проекта у себя на сайте?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Я создал проект на github.com
Создал доску с задачами.
Но когда я её хотел отобразить у себя на сайте в iframe, у меня это не получилось.

Как можно настроить права, что бы отображать доску у себя на сайте ?

Comment: Не уверен, что github предназначен для этого

Comment: А как думаете ? получится получить строку страницы на своём сайте. и прописать base tag  что бы загружались скрипты. ?